# Which pixel formats are supported on macOS/iOS?

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, core-video, core-media

From the [Pixel Format Identifiers documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers):

> Core Video does not provide support for all of these formats; this list defines only their names.

How do I know which pixel formats are supported by Core Video?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Nope, `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` (not in `CMPixelFormatType`) is also supported.

---

As described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54355961/815742) to a similar question, the subset of pixel formats defined in `CMPixelFormatType` are probably the ones that are supported by macOS/iOS.