# Difference between `CMPixelFormatType` and `CVPixelFormatType`?

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, core-video, core-media

The [`CMPixelFormatType` constants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmpixelformattype) are a subset of the [`CVPixelFormatType` constants](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers).

Additionally, in the `CMPixelFormatType` comments, it says:

> In general, CoreVideo CVPixelFormatType constants may be used too.

What’s the difference between these two groups of constants? Why are the `CMPixelFormatType` constants only a subset of the `CVPixelFormatType` constants? Are they special?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Nope, `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` (not defined in `CMPixelFormatType`) is also supported.

---

My guess is that the subset of pixel formats defined by `CMPixelFormatType` are the ones that are actually supported in macOS/iOS whereas the pixel formats defined by `CVPixelFormatType` are all the known pixel formats in the world.

This is hinted in the [Pixel Format Identifiers documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers):

> Core Video does not provide support for all of these formats; this list defines only their names.